# $text search is not supported aws mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aws-documentdb, aws-documentdb-mongoapi

I want to do a text search based on weightage. So used below mongo query

**Query:**

db.stores.find( { $text: { $search: ""coffee shop"" } } )

This query works for MongoDB but, aws documentDB is not supporting $text search. Is there any alternate way to do a text search in MongoDB which also supports aws documentDB?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65131425/feature-not-supported-text-in-document-db-with-mongodb-3-6-compatiability/65131697#65131697

Comment: AWS MongoDB is not MongoDB. It is a clone Umang. I suggest the Atlas Free Tier. It's actually from the people that build the open source database and has more features. You can run it on AWS, actually. In fact, it even has a search engine backed in. `$search`. It must be the first stage in an aggregation pipeline, but it's the state of the art stuff and not a clone of itself.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate approach is to integrate an external search technilogy like Apache Lucene or Amazon OpenSearch using change streams to populate the search platform and calling it directly to perform text searches.