# Error : "pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Feature not supported: splitVector" While using ReadFromMongoDB in Apache Beam

Tags: mongodb, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, aws-documentdb, aws-documentdb-mongoapi

I am trying to read data from mongodb(which is running in AWS Documentdb) and write to bigquery.

I have written python code for that and running it using python3 command. My pipeline string looks like below:

```
p | ReadFromMongoDB(uri='mongodb://documentdb_url:27017',db="test_db",coll="test_collection") | beam.Map(json_parse_fun) | 'WriteToBigQuery' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery('target_bq_table', write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
```

json_parse_fun() converts mongodb data into JSON file.

but when i run this code, dataflow job fails with below error:

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Feature not supported: splitVector
```

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB does not "run in DocumentDB".

DocumentDB is an imitation database implementing some of MongoDB's features. You found a feature it doesn't implement.

See ["Feature not supported: $text" in document db with mongodb 3.6 compatiability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65131425/feature-not-supported-text-in-document-db-with-mongodb-3-6-compatiability/65131697#65131697).